# Angular keeps recompiling on WSL

Tags: node.js, angular, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use WSL to run Angular on Ubuntu bash on Windows. When I serve the app with `ng serve --aot --poll 1000` it compiles an run normally, but after just a few seconds it recompiles with the following output:

```
Date: 2019-06-14T19:02:29.593Z - Hash: 7db119822f78e22dc95b - Time: 4996ms
9 unchanged chunks
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Note that I make no changes to any file and it only happens when the app is open on the browser.

I am using Node version 11.15.0, npm 6.7.0 and Angular CLI 8.0.3

The original files were created on a Ubuntu machine and I am downloading them with GIT. The app runs smoothly on Ubuntu, that is why I think the problem is with my setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, on Windows when passing `--poll` it will trigger a recompile of the app on the specified time. Removing `--poll 1000` solved the issue.